# 2.82 fluid simulation size (scale) / particles size (scale)

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation, scale

I try to use 2.82 to play fluid simulation. First I use default size and run simulation and get some result. The particles seem well in view port (as my Screenshot).

[image]
[image]

My domain size is 1.919 and my flow behavior is Geometry. It seem the particles are separate.

**Here is my question.** When I scale down both domain and flow about 20 times, the particles doesn't scale down and look squeeze together (as my Screenshot). Is there any setup to change this particles size? Or this size doesn't affect the result of simulation? Thanks you for reading my question!

(I realize 'Resolution Division' in fluid simulation. My idea is to simulate a small area and get more detail where I want to simulate.)

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should always apply "SCALE" (control+A) to the domain, so the scale (x,y,z) are 1.
The size of the water particles are defined also by the "mesh" part of the simulation (here you can configure the size of the water spheres)

Answer (score 0):

i did it by changing the unit scale down in scene properties

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)